# Equally spaced out pins for block-components in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm trying to build a schematic using the Electrical Engineering toolbox, but for the integrated circuit component toolbox, I cant seem to get the pins to spaceout equally when I remove some. Does anybody have any ideas? Thank you in advance!